# Python text game

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to make a text game, that will start off with a timer that will add 1 letter to form a string every 0.05 seconds, so it looks like someone is typing a sentence.

Ex. "Hello, this is a test" would start off with h then e then l then l then o, with a time period between the letters being printed on the line.

```
import time
string = "Hello, this is a test"
count=1
while count >0:
    time.sleep(0.05)
    print(string[:1]),
```

That is the code i tried, but i'm just lost and have no idea how to continue. Any ideas on how i can make this work?

Comment: If you randomize the sleep time from 0.03 to 0.08 or so, then it will look more like somebody actually typing, especially if you always use very short times for spaces and repeated letters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace your `while` loop with a `for` loop iterating over the string you want to print. That'll give you each letter in turn and stop your loop at the end. I also recommend placing this behaviour in a function like so:

```
def typeText(text, delay=0.05):
  for character in text:
    print character,
    time.sleep(delay)

typeText("Hello, this is a text")
```

To solve the problem of the spaces, you then have 3 options, in order from most to least side effects:

- Switch to python3 which uses `print` as a function with an `end` argument that you can set to the empty string;
- `from __future__ import print_function` which will give you the same print function without all the other caveats from python3;
- replace `print` by `sys.stdout.write()`. This function is what print wraps around by default

Comment: Are you using either Python 3.x or the `from __future__...` statement? If so, you'll need to change that line for `print(character, end='')`

Comment: I'm using 2.7, i added in the print_function and it seems to work now

Comment: One last thing, the >>> from the interpreter appears at the right side of the string instead of underneath, any idea why?

Comment: That would be because we're not printing any newlines after printing. Just add a call to `print()` after the loop

Answer (score 2):

This is the way to do it,

EDIT: Since OP does not want spaces after printing each character,so i set `end=''`

```
    import time
    string = "Hello, this is a test"
    count=0
    while count<len(string):
          time.sleep(0.05)
          print (string[count],end='')
          count = count+1
```

Comment: There appear to be spaces between the string when printed, ex. "H e l l o", any idea how i can fix that ?

Comment: @MattWalker, Try to add comma after print, like `print string[count],`

Comment: Spaces come when you have space in string itself.Could be console specific, no idea.

Comment: @RomanBodnarchuk yeah i did that before i ran it, just runs it on one line with the spaces. I tried print (" ".join(string[count])) , but it didn't work

Comment: @SrinivasReddyThatiparthy: Not in this case. Print adds a space after every printing

Comment: @AlexBrault It didn't know that.Thanks for that. Matt see alex comment.

Comment: I think @AlexBrault knows the answer.

Comment: @MattWalker You can put `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of your file, and then use [Python 3's print function](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#print) to remove the spaces from each `print` using the `sep` and `end` arguments: `print(string[count], sep='', end='')`

Comment: @HenryKeiter he is using Python 3. He don't need to do that.I am updating the answer.Thanks for that.

Comment: @SrinivasReddyThatiparthy His question is tagged 2.7, and he has a comma outside the parentheses. It doesn't look like Python 3 to me.

Comment: You'll want `end=''`" rather than `sep`. Sep is when you print multiple things with one print, end is for the end of everything

Comment: Where did @MattWalker say he's using Python 3? He tagged his question 2.7; I would be hesitant to change the tags without seeing some evidence that he is in fact using Python 3 already.

Comment: Well, he used print function,and i assumed that is the whole code he had. :)

Comment: @SrinivasReddyThatiparthy this is for 2.7 right? as i'm getting an error over end=''     print (string[count],end='')
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @SrinivasReddyThatiparthy: That's not the print function, that's a print statement with extraneous parentheses

Comment: @MattWalker Please put this statement at the top. `from __future__ import print_function`

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
import time
string = "Hello, this is a test"
count=1
for i in string:
    time.sleep(0.05)
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work (as you want it to work) because you have an **infinite loop** there.

You could write like this (just like improvement of your existing code):

```
import time
string = "Hello, this is a test"
count = len(string)
while count > 0:
    time.sleep(0.05)
    print(string[:1]),
    count -=1
```

**But** this is *not Pythonic*.

The only right way to do it here is to code it like this:

```
import time
string = "Hello, this is a test"
for letter in string:
    time.sleep(0.05)
    print letter
```

And this is *not* Pythonic too:

```
for i in range(len(string)):
    # Do something...
```

Comment: *What is Pythonic? / `for i in range(len(seq)):`? No. / Use `for obj in seq:`.*

Comment: I think I wrote the same

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to replace the 'while' with something like

```
for i in range(len(string)):
```

That'll iterate through the string.